# Who's the reference of this absolutely position element: the floating parent or the absolute grandparent?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

A "theoretical" css question.

I'd like to have some kind of clarification as to what is *supposed* to happen in this case...

---

Here's a summmed up version of my HTML...

```
<div id="some_navbar">
    <ul>
        <li id="plain_li"><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
        <li id="dropdown_li"><a href="#">GOODBYE</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">FOR NOW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FOR GOOD</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's my stylesheet

```
#some_navbar {
    position: absolute; /* A positioned ancestor does exist. */
    top: 0.75em;
    right: 1.5em;
}

#some_navbar li,
#some_navbar a {
    display: block;
}

#some_navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#some_navbar > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#some_navbar > ul > li {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    }

#dropdown_li > ul {
    display: none;
}

#dropdown_li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
}
```

I [read](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) that *absolute* means that "the element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element".

So does this mean that my last selector element ( `#dropdown_li:hover > ul` ) is positioned relative to its floating parent `li` (in other words, does floating qualify as positioning in this sense) or to its also absolutely positioned great grandparent ( `#some_navbar` )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating does not count as positioning. "Positioning" means a value other than `static` for the `position` property. So `#dropdown_li:hover > ul` would be positioned relative to `#some_navbar` since it's the closest ancestor with a `position` that isn't `static`

Comment: Crystal clear explanation. Exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

I deconstructed your code for you in this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/RArnone/horpqx5z/)

It will show you that the element in question is not "relative" to it's floated parent. For that to be the case you would have to set the parent element to `position: relative`.

```
#some_navbar {
    position: absolute; /* A positioned ancestor does exist. */
    border: 1px solid red;
    left: 5em;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

#some_navbar li,
#some_navbar a {
    display: block;
}

#some_navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#some_navbar > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#some_navbar > ul > li {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    }

#dropdown_li > ul {
    display: none;
}

#dropdown_li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid green;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```